# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to build a classifier of tweets using Python 3. 
I got the following error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'id'

when I ran the following code:

```
train_df['id'] = train_df.id.apply(lambda x: int(x))
train_df['friends_count'] = train_df.friends_count.apply(lambda x: int(x))
train_df['followers_count'] = train_df.followers_count.apply(lambda x: 0 if x=='None' else int(x))
train_df['friends_count'] = train_df.friends_count.apply(lambda x: 0 if x=='None' else int(x))
```

The dataset looks like

[image]

and it is a csv file. I would like to have a list of all the columns in the dataset rather than scrolling manually. I checked the version of panda and it seems to be already updated. I am pretty new in using Python, so I hope you can help me to figure out what I am doing wrong.
Thanks

EDIT:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-13c1484f8b58> in <module>
      2 train_df = df.copy()
      3 #train_df['id'] = train_df.id.apply(lambda x: int(x))
----> 4 train_df['friends_count'] = train_df.friends_count.apply(lambda x: int(x))
      5 train_df['followers_count'] = train_df.followers_count.apply(lambda x: 0 if x=='None' else int(x))
      6 train_df['friends_count'] = train_df.friends_count.apply(lambda x: 0 if x=='None' else int(x))

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   4374         IE10                   404           0.08
   4375         Chrome                 200           0.02
-> 4376 
   4377         >>> df.reindex(new_index, fill_value='missing')
   4378                       http_status response_time

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'friends_count'
```

Comment: Your header row is being read as a data row. How are you loading the CSV?

Comment: which line was the error from? Can you provide the full error path please, thanks!

Comment: For Chris Heald: I am using `df = pd.read_csv('path',   sep=',', header=None,error_bad_lines=False)`

Comment: I updated the question with the full error path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your columns are simply shown as `0,1,2,...`. You are probably interested to use the first row as column names. 
You need to first convert the first data row to columns in the  following way:

```
train_df.columns = train_df.iloc[0]
```

or

```
train_df.rename(columns=train_df.iloc[0])
```

Then you will be able to do the current operations you are doing.
You can also remove the current header row in the following way:

```
train_df.drop(train_df.index[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html

Read this article.

You need to learn a bit more about pandas and how it works before the answer to this question would even be helpful.